# DateTimeField and change date in view

Tags: django

I have this code

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)
```

in models.py. In view I get the object:

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=2)
```

and i wish change the date for the year ahead. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be exact with leap years:

```
import datetime, calendar

obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=2)
next_date = obj.date + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
if calendar.isleap(obj.date.year) and obj.date <= datetime.datetime(obj.date.year, 2, 29) or \
   calendar.isleap(next_date.year) and obj.date > datetime.datetime(obj.date.year, 2, 28):
    next_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
obj.date = next_date
obj.save()
```

Comment: Okay, fixed.  Unfortunately not as simple now, but still better than using an external library (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

If 365 day is close enough for you the most simple solution to do this is:

```
import datetime

obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=2)
obj.date = obj.date + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
obj.save()
```

If you need more precision (for leap years for example) use the relative datetime from the mxdatetime package:

http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/doc/#RelativeDateTime